# How to quit from nested Coroutines in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am creating topdown puzzle game, and I use grid-based movement. I created a code, that moves character and, if character is pushing box, it pushes box also. But I want box to see if there is anything behind it, and if there is something, stop all movement (itself's and character's). So I created two similar Coroutine functions:

First, for player movement

```
private IEnumerator PlayerMove(Vector2 direction)
    {

        // check for wall collisions
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(playerTransform.position, direction, raycastDistance, wallLayer).collider is not null)
        {
            Animate(Animations.CantMove);
            yield break;
        }

        // check for box collisions
        else if (Physics2D.Raycast(playerTransform.position, direction, raycastDistance, box.boxLayer).collider is not null)
        {
            if ()
        }

        // changing fields
        isMoving = true;
        isPlayersTurn = false;


        // actual moving
        float elapsedTime = 0f;

        origPos = playerTransform.position;
        targetPos = origPos + direction;

        while (elapsedTime < timeToMove)
        {
            playerTransform.position = Vector2.Lerp(origPos, targetPos, (elapsedTime / timeToMove));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        playerTransform.position = targetPos;


        // changing fields
        isMoving = false;
        isBotTurn = true;
    }
```

And second, similar, for box movement:

```
public IEnumerator Move(Vector2 direction, float raycastDistance, LayerMask wallLayer, float timeToMove)
    {             
        // check for wall collisions
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, direction, raycastDistance, wallLayer).collider is not null)
        {
            //do something
        }



        // actual moving
        float elapsedTime = 0f;

        Vector2 origPos, targetPos;

        origPos = transform.position;
        targetPos = origPos + direction;

        while (elapsedTime < timeToMove)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(origPos, targetPos, (elapsedTime / timeToMove));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        transform.position = targetPos;
    }
```

At the beginning of second method I check if there is no wall behind the box using Physics2D.Raycast() method. If it notices something, I want to exit both PlayerMove() and BoxMove(), but if it doesn't, I want both to proceed. I tried using exceptions, but it seems that Coroutines don't like them. Is there any way to do something with this?

Comment: Consider using a simple time-based interpolation function instead of coroutines as the latter if used incorrectly is akin to `Application.DoEvents`.  Additionally it teaches bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the execution of the current coroutine you can use `yield break;`

To stop the execution of another coroutine you can use [StopCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html).

```
private Coroutine playerMoveCoroutine;

public void StartMoving(Vector2 direction)
{
    playerMoveCoroutine = StartCoroutine(PlayerMove(direction));
}

public void StopMoving()
{
    if(moveCoroutine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(moveCoroutine);
        moveCoroutine = null;
    }
}
```

So stopping both of the coroutines could be done like this:

```
if (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, direction, raycastDistance, wallLayer).collider is not null)
{
    player.StopMoving();
    yield break;
}
```